# Character encoding .txt to Python 2.7 to .csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, character-encoding

I am reading in a text file into Python 2.7, re-organizing the data in a pandas data frame and then saving the results as a .csv file. The data in the .csv file displays encoding errors (Â and ï»¿ scattered throughout the data). I have tried decoding the data from utf-8 when I read it in and then encoding it when sending it out, but I am still experiencing the same errors in the data.

Here's a simplified version of my current code:

```
respNum=0
f = open(path+filename+".txt", "r")

for line in f.xreadlines():
    df["DATA"][respNum] = line
    respNum += 1            

f.close()

df.to_csv(outfile+filename+".csv",encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Are you using pandas to read and save the csv files? Where does `df` come from?

Comment: It sounds like a typical BOM issue. Try using `encoding='utf-8-sig'` at readtime. FYI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: What is the initial encoding and what to you want as final encoding? If unsure what it your system and its default language?

Comment: @ivankeller Â and ï»¿ does not look like a BOM problem for me but does look like reading UTF8 as Latin1.

Comment: @ivankeller Thank you for the help! Using encoding='utf-8-sig' fixed all the issues. The resource you shared is also helpful.

Comment: @meyaoo Can you post your comment as an answer? Thanks!